# Chic Le (Freak - Freak Out!)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I may stick or be a stick,
>   or touch a part of you with the same name,
>   for perhaps hours.
>
> Looking back, I stick up,
>   or touch a part of you with the same name,
>   for only moments.

Looking back, we appear stuck-up, but what am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you are:

> **GUM**

*I may stick or be a stick,*

> Some forms of gum can be used as an adhesive ('*I may stick*'). Equally, you can have *a stick* of chewing gum.

*or touch a part of you with the same name,*
*for perhaps hours.*

> If you chew gum it could stay in your mouth (where it touches your *gums*) 'for perhaps hours'.

*Looking back, I stick up,*

> The word GUM in reverse (i.e. '*Looking back*') spells **MUG**, a word that can be used to mean '*stick up*' in the sense of a highwayman or robber 'mugging' somebody of their valuables.

*or touch a part of you with the same name,*
*for only moments.*

> The word 'mug' can also be used (a) for a drinking vessel, and (b) as a slang term for the face (thanks @hexomino for this improvement to my original answer). The two may come into contact with each other briefly ('*for only moments*') when you take a sip of a drink.

The ending flavourtext also has meaning: *Looking back, we appear stuck-up*

> Taking 'we' to mean the plural form, GUMS, and 'Looking back' to mean reversing the letter order, we appear **SMUG**, a synonym for 'stuck-up' as a behaviour.

As for the title:

> [**CHICLE**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicle) is a type of naturally occurring gum used as an ingredient in many chewing gum products.

Comment: Also the backwards word can mean face so it touches that too. Nice answer.

Comment: @hexomino I like that - I'll edit that in, thanks :)

Comment: rot13(fzht) for end flavourtext. ('Looking back', in question, I should've used 'up'.)

Comment: I guess the "ending flavourtext" is rather "looking back" applied to the plural?